# Comparing a population mean with another population's sample mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, mean, sample, population

We are currently studying a difference in ESG performance between two groups of companies and initially looked at doing a two sample t-test but now have a question on which method to use since we realized that what we deemed to be our sample is actually our a population (yes, we suck at stats).

Hence we have

Population 1: Average ESG Score x (known).

Sample 2: Indicated Average ESG Score f y (known)

Population 2: Average ESG Score y (unknown)

--

Rather than two samples and two populations.

Is it appropriate to compare the means of Population 1 to Sample 2? Should this not increase the confidence/power due to removing a factor of uncertainty due to not having to sample group 1?

Can't find an appropriate test for this scenario, very thankful for any guidance on this!

Comment: We looked at one solution to get around this, which was to classify population 1 as a non-random sample of a larger population of companies and essentially stating that the results are not fully representative of the larger population, but serving as an indication that higher ESG performance might be found in the larger population compared to population 2. Is this utter nonsense or would we be able to write this in a thesis?

Comment: I confess that I don't entirely understand what the situation here is, but it seems to me that you want to test whether a sample (Sample 2) differs significantly/is sampled from a different population than a known population (Population 1). If that's the case, then you just have a one-sample t-test

Comment: IMHO, this situation is still too vague to give responsible advice. Please specify population and sample sizes, and give sample means and standard deviations. Have looked at histograms, boxplots, normal probability plots to get an idea whether populations are normal?